# Laravel - Problem Of How To Tune Strange Behavior With Sending Text Message

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have a very special problem and I don't know how to deal with it.

I have web App in Laravel, when i open `index` page, I receive text message to my mobile phone.
Problem is, sometimes I receive 2 messages or 3, sometimes 1.
Is there a tool how to debug this strange behavior which is not always the same?

A few words about my code:
user opens the page, and because its first visit `Session` doesn't have attribute `message_sent` and `SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $id_message, $smsCode, $newDateFormat);` is executed. After that `Session` has `message_sent` and can't be sent again, for example if I refresh the page.

`SendTextMessage::SendMessage()` is Class in Laravel Helpers.

`controller code`:

```
public function index($url_attribute, $id_message, Request $request)
{      
    if(!Session::has('message_sent'))
    {
        $user = User::where('id_message', $id_message)->first()->toArray();
        $phoneNumber = $user['mobile_phone'];
        $smsCode = $user['sms_code'];
        $newDateFormat = date("d.m.yy", strtotime($smsExpirationTime));

        $request->session()->flash('message', 'Text message sended.' );

        SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber,$id_message, $smsCode, $newDateFormat);
        Session::put('message_sent', true);

    }

    return view('login');
    
}
```

`SendTextMessage Class`:

```
class SendTextMessage 
{
    public static function SendMessage($phoneNumber, $id_message, $smsCode, $newDateFormat)
    {
        $sms = new Connect();
        $sms->Create("user","pass",Connect::AUTH_PLAIN);
        $sms->Send_SMS($phoneNumber,"Message");
        $sms->Logout();
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any tip or help.

UPDATE:

problem is only in Chrome.
Edge and internet explorer are fine.

Comment: Is it the same msg, sent 3 times, or 3 different msgs? Maybe the SMS provider retries bcs sending failed, but didn't really fail?  Add a unique code to the msg to see. Do the msgs all arrive at the same time, or spread out over seconds/minutes/..?

Comment: 1, 2 or 3 same msgs with 2-3 sec delay. 10 times i got 1 msg  and 11 try give me two same msgs.

Comment: OK so you need to find out if your code is running 3 times, or if the SMS provider/network is resending ... add some logging?

Comment: how can log function what request sending?

Comment: If you add logging in your code, with timestamps, you will see if there is 3 log records, and 3 times, or one.  That will tell you if your code is running 3 times, or if the problem is related to the provider somehow resending.

Comment: mamy thanks, is there any tutorial on web how add logging to laravel what exactly controller do?

Comment: [`Log::debug('An informational message.');`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#writing-log-messages)

Comment: I guess this might be something to do with Chrome pre-fetching the page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215875/chrome-loading-script-twice-when-manually-typing-url-to-move-to-next-page, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598171/kohana-model-saved-twice This is probably also a good reason to stick with [standard conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) and use a POST for this, rather than GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maybe try to change the way you use Laravel Session.
You indicated that it was working fine on some browsers, that means your server-side code is correct so far, but there is someting messing with Chrome… From there,
if you take a quick look at [the Laravel Session doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#configuration), you'll see that Session can be stored in `cookies`, and I bet that this is your actual setup (check in your .env file the SESSION_DRIVER constant, or in your config/session.php file).

If so, to confirm that this cookies-based session setting is the culprit, you might want to change the Session config to make it browser-independent: any other option than cookies will work, the `database` or `file` options might be the easier to setup… And if it works I would strongly encourage you to keep using this no-cookie setting to make your code browser-safe.

Comment: ````'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')```` so sessions are stored in ````storage/sessions/````. do you thing this can be problem for chrome ?

Comment: @ JBA  Is it worth investing time and setting up a seassion relational database?

Comment: If that's already file-based there is no need to test the database option IMHO, although this issue beeing browser dependent is really strange. Did you also double-check that your .env file does not override this setting? the SESSION_DRIVER in the .env could override that config default value…

Comment: my .env file dont has SESSION_DRIVER in :/

Comment: If that's on your server and you're note 100% sure what the setting value is in the end, you might just push a test debug page where you would ask laravel to echo the value of your config('session.driver') value…

Comment: If you're confident you're not on cookies, then it's Chrome that is messing up Laravel's Sessions system… A workaround I would try then would be to use the native php session without the Laravel Session layer, just to eliminate any unknown behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227769/discussion-between-jba-and-novice).

Answer (score 4):

As this script runs on server-side the browser shouldn't be an issue. Based on your code provided, there is no clear answer to give here.

Please try the following in order to debug your problem:

1. Log messages at each stage of the script in order to see which part was called how often. That will help you to locate the problem. You can use `\Log::error("Message")` to do that.
2. Once you know where the problem might be, try to log "decision" making / mission critical variables to logile as well. E.g. `\Log::error($session)` so that you can understand why that problem might occur. One reason could be that you have a bad configured session caching or your cookies might be messed up. At some point there is probably a piece of data not the way you expect it to be.